# WPF Freezable Warning on a plain ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm recieving the following message:

`System.Windows.Freezable Warning: 4 : CanFreeze is returning false because at least one DependencyProperty on the Freezable is animated.; Freezable='System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform'; Freezable.HashCode='65850542'; Freezable.Type='System.Windows.Media.TranslateTransform'`

On my plain, unstyled ComboBoxes i.e.:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LookupUnits}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedUnit}">
    <ComboBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Delete"
        Command="{Binding Path=ClearComboBoxCommand}"
        CommandParameter="LookupUnit" />
    </ComboBox.InputBindings>
 </ComboBox>
```

I've removed all the styles, from the resource dictionaries etc, so I'm not sure why its appearing.  It only appears when your first drop down the list and when you click on one of the items in the list.

This on a WPF .NET 4 app.

Comment: there should be some involved code elsewhere. Looks like there is some animation on TranslateTransform.

Comment: This is because when you change your selection your selected item changes and your combobx style also gets change, so please try using Style={x:null} in your combobox and then try. or i would say please check Combobox.CanFreeze property, i think it is true.

Comment: @AshokRathod why changing the selection makes the comboBox style change? you can see that in the code above? if not as I said, there should be some involved code ***elsewhere***.

Comment: I removed the styles from app.xaml's merge dictionary.  I've left the files in the project though.  There are no resources defined on the page or the grid of this page or any other.  This is what's confusing I thought it was me mucking up a style. But its still doing it when they've been removed.